# Use Angular 5 service call inside Angular 1 application

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services, ng-upgrade

In my scenario, I am having a complex angular 1 application which is using another script file(separate single JS file which is downloaded directly when URL is launched). This is script file is also coded in Angular 1.6 which we have migrated as a Angular 5 component now. Using webpack I have 2 bundle files generated(vendor.js and main.client.js).

My question is that I wanted to add those scripts and call a angular 5 service call from angular 1 application without much code change in angular 1 application. If I add the  in index.html along with bundle scripts of angular 5, it launches as a seperate application in the browser. But what I require is to only call a particular service in angular 5 via angular JS controller.

I was able to achieve the concept of keeping it as Hybrid application. But that doesn't help for me. Please share your thoughts and experience. It would really help me a lot since I am breaking my head for past 1 week.. Thanks in advance.